# How to view RAM commit with MSI Afterburner/Riva Tuner?

Tags: memory, resource-monitor, osd, msi-afterburner

Looking for a way to output the value shown in the 'Commit' column of Resource Monitor on the screen overlay provided with [Riva Tuner](https://www.guru3d.com/content-page/rivatuner.html):

[image]

I have [PerfCount 0.9](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/performance-counter-monitoring-plugin.304772/) installed which "*allows available Performance Counters to be added to the RivaTuner Hardware Monitoring module*", however I can't seem to find any memory setting that reflects committed RAM, only RAM in use.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so my wizard friend just came in and explained how to do this, and it was quite lengthy, so please hang in here while I explain how to do this. It should be noted that the previously mentioned [Perfcount 0.9](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/performance-counter-monitoring-plugin.304772/) is not needed to accomplish the task.

## How to display Committed Memory in Riva Tuner

- Open Riva Tuner and at the very bottom of the GUI select 'SETUP'
  [image]
- Next Click the 'plugins' tab then double click 'OverlayEditor.dll'
  [image]
- In the Overlay Editor window that has appeared click on 'Data Sources' and click then 'Edit'
  [image]
- Next, click 'Add'
  [image]
- Then change the 'Data provider' to 'Windows performance counter'. Scroll down below in the 'Sensor' column field and click on 'Process'. This will open a sub menu where we will chose the 'Page File Bytes" then click 'OK'

[image]

- With the 'Page File Bytes' entry selected in the previously opened window named 'Overlay data sources', click the 'Setup' button:
  [image]
- A new window named 'Data source settings' will open. Here we will select the process name of the program we wish to have the overlay displayed over. This is done in the 'Instance name or Index' field (in this example I have inputted 'bio4' as the process name).
- We can also choose which type of units to display the memory usage in (I have chose MB in this example).
- In this same window we will need to input a value of `x/1048576` in the 'Correction Formula' field.
- When these tasks are complete, click 'OK' to close the 'Data source settings' window, and the click 'OK' to close the 'Overlay Data Sources' window.
  [image]
- Next double click on the newly added layer in the 'Overlay editor window (it should appear as a colorized string of text overlaid on the black screen:
  [image]
- A new window will appear labelled 'Layer properties'. In the 'Hypertext' field we can set the name of our overlay that will appear in the OSD. Once this is done click the '+' sign just to the right:
  [image]
- Another new window will appear named 'Add embeded object'. Change the Data source to 'Page File Bytes' and select the 'Add current macro' and press 'OK'
  [image]
- In the previously opened 'Layer properties' window the 'Hypertext' field will now output: `Commited Memory:%Page File Bytes% MB`. We can edit or delete any of this part, with the exception of `%Page File Bytes%`. When we are done with this part, simply press 'OK'.
- Now we can close the 'Overlay editor' window (the one with the black screen), and when prompted, SAVE.
- In the final window that remains open we must ensure that the checkmark is selected in the OverlayEditor.dll entry, and then press 'OK'
  [image]

Comment: nice! good answer and well illustrated.